# regex to extract a number from strings using a template

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Suppose to have multiple values that contains number following a pattern:

- 1a-p1_2023   -> extract 1 (the middle one)
- 1a-p12_2023  -> extract 12
- 1a-p7_2023   -> extract 7
- 1a-p145_2023 -> extract 145

the pattern is `1a-p#_2023` where `#` represent the number to be found (of any digits). Note that

1. The pattern can contains other digits (fixed and not wanted)
2. The pattern can contain letter and/or special characters
3. The pattern can contain the target digit(s) at the end, the start or in the middle
4. I want to use a special character (e. g. `#` )to identify uniquely the position of the target digits (not used in the other part of the template)

I think this could be obtain with regex with one of the following strategies:

1. extract the digit(s) extracting the part where `#` is
2. replace any other part of the string with the null character ""

The goal is to achieve that with `REGEXEXTRACT` or `REGEXREPLACE` in Google Sheets.

My tests:

```
"\d+"
```

can't be used because the first group of digit could not be the target.

```
"\#(.*?)\#"
```

extracts the part between 2 "#" but i can't extend the regex replacing a single `#` with half of the template. Also, a regex with the whole template string not splitted is possible?

Comment: So, `p\\(\d+)`? Or a more restrictive, `1a-p(\d+)_2023`?

Comment: Thank you sir @WiktorStribiżew you make my day. I can go with =REGEXEXTRACT(A1;REPLACE("1a-p#_2023";"#";"(\d+)"))

Comment: Ah, so there is no backslash after `p`.

Comment: no, there it is I copied it wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `#` character is used in your template to represent some one or more digits, you can use a `1a-p#_2023` template and replace `#` with `(\d+)` to create the full pattern:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;SUBSTITUTE("1a-p#_2023";"#";"(\d+)"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eG38Dv/1).

Note the capturing group, it is necessary for the `REGEXEXTRACT` to return only that number captured into Group 1, not the whole match value.

Answer (score -1):

There's a helpful website for testing regex [here](https://regex101.com/).

The expression `".*\\(\d+).*"` will ignore any characters before the slash (`\\` in the expression) in your test cases (with `.*`). The number is matched by `(\d+)`. The remaining portion of the string is ignored by `.*`.

This does, however, assume that the slash will be present in every case.